# Yii2 site controller cannot render any files (forbidden#403)

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

I worked with  RBAC in my project which worked fine in overall my project wherever I checked if particular user can perform specified action.

But the actions that I didnt went thorugh RBAC in site controller are not being rendered from any users.

My code that I used to access to the function in site controller:

[image: code]

My function that needs to be accessed in site controller.

[image: controller]

Comment: Need Code. Your Required Code Is Mandatory For Us To Figure Out The Actual Issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is the code problem in this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add additional access rule to your behavior in SiteController:

```
        [
            'allow'   => true,
            'actions' => [
                'hofview'
            ],
            'roles'   => ['?'],    // it means user not logged in can access this action
        ],
```

Comment: Great ;) please upvote if it helped and mark as answered so it will help me too :)

Comment: done. :D I had a new problem about dynamic form.. Can you help me on that one too.

Comment: Sorry friend, im not using wbraganca so not this time :)